# Live Update like Facebook ticker

Tags: facebook

I wonder how the technique with live update could be implemented? What is it's concept? Keep on access db? Will this consume resources? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you looking to implement a similar function or are you just curious?

Comment: curious but not going to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy to implement method is to use Ajax polling. Here is a **untested** example of a concept of it with JQuery.

```
<script language=javascript>
var int= setInterval("getUpdates",5000); // Every 5 seconds

function getUpdates()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/get/new/notifications/page/'    
  }).done(function(data)
  {
      alert(data);
  });
}
</script>
```

This will call the getUpdates() function every 5 seconds, and return whats output from the page into the data variable.

Comment: every 5 minutes? this won't consume the resource seriously?

Comment: I'm sure with 1000 users, the server would take a bit of load :P

Not sure performance wise; Hence why I put *Untested*.